# Suggestions with pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I've a problem with pagination. The php code of pagination query is:

```
$ <? if (isset($_GET["page"])) { 

    $Page = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $_GET["page"]);
} else {
    $Page = 0;
}
$limit       = 10;
$StartFrom  = $limit * $Page;
$TotalFiles = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM linkuri WHERE `categorie` = 'Afaceri' AND status = 1"));
$TotalPages = floor($TotalFiles / $limit); ?>
```

And code to display it:

```
$i = 0; while ($TotalPages >= $i) { echo '<a class="active imgf" style="opacity: 1;margin-bottom:3px; margin-top:3px;" href="afaceri.php?page='.$i.'">'.($i+1).'</a>';$i++;}
```

The problem is I am trying to make the display as: `PAGES: "BACK" 1 2 3 4 5 "NEXT"`

Comment: There's an excellent video tutorial on how to do this here: youtube.com/phpapplied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would like to suggest an improvement on your query. To count the total rows use:

```
SELECT count(*) as `totalpost` FROM linkuri WHERE `categorie` = 'Afaceri' AND status = 1
```

Then, you are create that pagination by doing something like this:

```
$totalPost = 50; //Dummy total post
$limit = 10;

$pages = $totalPost / $limit; //Giving 5

//Now we know there are five pages
for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++) {
  echo $i; // Better echo something like <a href="link">$i</a>
}
```

<sub>P.S: This is a very basic example</sub>

After you get the hang of how to create the pagination effect, check this tutorial

> [How to paginate with PHP?](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/)

Answer (score 0):

And if you do not want to execute two long queries with same conditions, then consider testing this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, * FROM foo WHERE bar ORDER BY ouch
```

and then after that

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS found
```

First query gives you results with your conditions and limit, second one gives all record count without limit